# How to create a timeseries heatmap for a group of countries in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c5kCbsffeoOnvVqQfgqYtRYwwHJurPGW/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103277115443997362552&rtpof=true&sd=true) that has daily data about Covid19 for many countries. I have applied PCA and I have found the scores of the observations. I want to create a heatmap using only the scores in the PC1 in which the x-axis will be time and in the y-axis will be the name of every European country. For example, I want something like this:

[image: this].

Does anyone know how to do this? I have searched a lot and I haven't found something yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
brk <- c(-15, -10, -5, 0, 1, 2, Inf)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(scales)
p <- df %>%
  filter(continent == 'Europe' & date < '2020-05-30') %>% # filtered by date range because too much
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = location, fill = PC1)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = hue_pal()(7), breaks = brk) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))

ggplotly(p)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, I want to thank you a lot for your answer. Secondly, I want this graph to have all the date range. Also, I want the names of the countries to be prensented more clearly

Comment: I am trying to solve this question with the example in this site https://rkabacoff.github.io/datavis/Other.html#heatmaps

Comment: I made some changes and the result is very close to what I wanted. Thank you so much!!!